# ARMv7 T3 encoding for adds

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb, immediate-operand, instruction-encoding

[image]
I can't tell how to determine the following:

`i`, 10th bit on the left.

`imm3`, what's the difference for this one with imm8?

Comment: The `i`, `imm3` and `imm8` bits are joined to form a 32 bit immediate using the `ThumbExpandImm` function as explained in the pseudo code.  Refer to the appendix for how this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fields i and imm3 apply a transformation to the imm8 constant in order to generate more 32 bit constants. Here is the [official documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/Application-Level-Architecture/Thumb-Instruction-Set-Encoding/32-bit-Thumb-instruction-encoding/Modified-immediate-constants-in-Thumb-instructions?lang=en) which sadly doesn't explain much. There is also a post on [The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210603-00/?p=105276) about it.

Edit: The link to the documentation is for ARMv7-A but you find identical text in ARMv7-M reference section A5.3.2